# How to check specific value of current array item?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Let's say I have the following (dynamically created) array for a quiz's it's question options:

```
"choices": [
    {
        "choice": "yes",
        "correct": 1
    },
    {
        "choice": "No",
        "correct": 0
    },
    {
        "choice": "Maybe",
        "correct": 0
    },

]
```

And I'm looping over them like this:

```
<div class="form-group" v-for="choice in choices">
    <label><input type="radio">{{ choice.choice }}</label><br>
</div>
```

This correctly outputs radio input elements for each single option within the array. My question is, how would I go about checking wether "correct" is true when clicking on one of the options?

Hope a superhero can help me out.

Comment: checking whether the correct option is pressed is possible in many ways. The question is, how do you want to react to it? Just in the view, or do you want to keep track of score somewhere? IS there a submit button too, or is the response immediate?

Comment: No there is a button for the next question, but if I know how to return a response when clicking on one of the choices I'm able to figure out how to implement it on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Use of ui frameworks like Vue and React differ vastly from utility libraries like jQuery. There's a certain philosophy oh how they works, and this case, it's good to remember that they bind data to the DOM. This becomes of importance when dealing with tasks like you have outlined. It seems that you'd like to deal with the task of managing the interaction at a lower level than what's needed.

here is an example that will update the value of selection based on the choice

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>Choices:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li class="form-group" v-for="(choice, index) in choices">
      <label>
        <input
               name="choices"
               type="radio"
               v-model="selectionIndex"
               :value="index" 
               >
        {{ choice.choice }}
      </label><br>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <pre>{{ selection }}</pre>
</div>
```

script

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    choices: [
      {
        "choice": "yes",
        "correct": 1
      },
      {
        "choice": "No",
        "correct": 0
      },
      {
        "choice": "Maybe",
        "correct": 0
      }


    ],
    selectionIndex: null,
  },
  computed:{
    selection() {
        return this.choices[this.selectionIndex] || null;
    }
  },
})
```

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/164706/

by using v-model, the value of selectionIndex is updated with the array index. A computed value can then be used to get use the selectionindex and the choices array to return the selected option.

Next you can add a function after pressing the button that checks the value of `correct`. You can set the button to disabled if `selectionIndex === null`

Answer (score 0):

Using your existing code,

You can just add an `onChange` event listener into the choice and pass the `index` of the choice. That index is used to determine which choice it is.

So your template should look like this:

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="form-group" v-for="(choice, index) in choices">
        <label><input type="radio" @change="choiceSelected(index)">{{ choice.choice }}</label><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

And your script will look like this:

```
new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data: {
        "choices": [
        {
            "choice": "yes",
            "correct": 1
        },
        {
            "choice": "No",
            "correct": 0
        },
        {
            "choice": "Maybe",
            "correct": 0
        },

    ]
  },
  methods: {
    choiceSelected: function(choice_index) {
        var target_choice = this.choices[choice_index];

          if (target_choice.correct) {
                alert('Your answer is correct!');
          } else {
                alert('Your answer is incorrect :(');
          }

    }
  }
})
```

Or just look at this JS Fiddle :) 
https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/166234/